# ArgoCD: run a specific pipeline after a specific succesful ArgoCD deploy

Tags: argocd, tekton-pipelines

We use ArgoCD Applications to deploy a set of Kubernetes resources. How can I start a specific pipeline after a specific succesful Application run?

First I thought that starting such a pipeline could be done from an ArgoCD PostSync. As I understand now, a PostSync is a general hook, not a specific hook for 1 ArgoCD application. Correct?

Let me simplify my question. I have 2 ArgoCD applications. I want to execute action 1 (eg start a pipeline 1) after a successful sync of application 1. And action 2 only after a successful sync of application 2. How can I specify that?

Applications:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/app1repo/apps-1.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: app1path
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: app1
```

And Application2:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: app2
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/app2repo/apps-2.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: app2path
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: app2
```

Action 1 should only be done after the succesfull sync of Application1:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: app-slack-notification-
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1-post-sync
        image: busybox
        command: ["echo", "This simulates an **app1** post sync action"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

And action 2 after the succesfull sync of Application2:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: app-slack-notification-
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app2-post-sync
        image: busybox
        command: ["echo", "This simulates an **app2** post sync action"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: yea, you would use the PostSync hook for that exact use case, so I'm not sure what your hesitation is. I do not understand what `a PostSync is a general hook, not a specific hook for 1 ArgoCD application` - Hooks are per application, so Im confused with your statement.

Comment: My question is in essence: how are hooks connected to a specific application?

Comment: ArgoCD adds an annotation (or label) to know which resources belongs to an app. I guess this is how ArgoCD identify hooks to run for a given app.

Comment: Can you please give an example? I have searched the internet but could not find an example for this.

Comment: your question was ab hooks, not how does ArgoCD manage resources. The hook is an annotation (as you can see from your post above) and the way Argo tracks resources is by labels, annotations, or both labels and annotations - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_tracking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the PostSync config files *in* the Helm chart.

When the Application updates, the PostSync is done as described in the Helm chart of the Application.